# RestKit .2 Posting Images to web service - Null Entity Error

Tags: objective-c, ios6, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using RestKit to post images to a web service and they're posting fine, with the server sending 200 back. What's happening is that I'm getting the following error:

> `***` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "resource_updated_at".'

Here is the method I'm using to post the image.. I'm hoping there's something obvious that I'm missing. I've found a similar post that mentions that core data stack might not be set up correctly, but I'm not sure how. I'm using RestKit to post other standard form data and it returns and maps just fine.

```
- (void)postImagesFromInventory:(NSManagedObject *)inventory {
    NSLog(@"######## postImagesFromInventory ########");

    // if there are photos that aren't synced, post the first one
    int postingImageNumber = 0;

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];

    // send for each image in inventory
    for (Image *image in [[inventory valueForKey:@"image"] allObjects]) {
        postingImageNumber = postingImageNumber + 1;
        [SVProgressHUD setStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posting image %d of %d for inventory %@", postingImageNumber, [[inventory valueForKey:@"image"] allObjects].count, [inventory valueForKey:@"asset_name"]]];

        // make sure it's not already synced
        if (![image valueForKey:@"synced"]) {
            NSLog(@"-------------------------------------");
            NSLog(@"need to post image for inventory %@",[inventory valueForKey:@"inventory_id"]);

            NSURL *imagePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[image valueForKey:@"path"]];

            // need to get my image from Asset Library
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            __block NSNumber *imageSize = nil;
            __block UIImage *myImage = nil;
            __block Image *blockImage = nil;
            __block NSData *blockImageData = nil;

            [library assetForURL:imagePath resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
                imageSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:asset.defaultRepresentation.size];

                // make the image available on callback
                blockImage = image;

                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);
                blockImageData = imageData;

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager multipartFormRequestWithObject:inventory method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:IMAGES_ENDPOINT parameters:@{@"auth_token":@"my_auth_token",@"image" : @{@"asset_inventory_id":[inventory valueForKey:@"inventory_id"],@"resource_content_type":@"image/jpeg",@"resource_file_name":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_image.jpg",[inventory valueForKey:@"asset_name"]],@"resource_file_size": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageSize]}} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
               [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                           name:@"image[resource]"
                                       fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_image.jpg",[inventory valueForKey:@"asset_name"]]
                                       mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }];

            RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectStore:_managedStore];
            [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"resource_updated_at":@"resource_updated_at"}];
            [mapping mappingForDestinationKeyPath:@"image"];


            RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

            [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

            RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                NSLog(@"operation successful");
            } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"operation failed");
            }];

            // queue up the operation
            [manager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

            // library access failure
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here's the `init` method where I set up the `RKManagedObjectStore`, in case that's relevant.

```
- (PSNDataSync *)init {
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network*", RKLogLevelDebug);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelDebug);

    PSNAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PSNAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    _managedStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[appDelegate managedObjectModel]];

    _currentInventory = nil;
    _imagesArray = nil;

    // initialize imagesArray for loading inventoryCollectionView
    _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    return self;
}
```

Here is the `Image class` that represents the `Core Data Entity`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Inventory;

@interface Image : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * path;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * resource_updated_at;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * synced;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Inventory *inventory;

@end
```

I'll put up the disclaimer that this is probably not the best code.. but please let me know if you see THE error :].

Comment: What's the definition of the 'Image' class and does it correctly match the definition in the data model? Has the class been edited since it was generated by Xcode?

Comment: Wain, I've added the Image class.. When you asked about the definition, I actually went in and deleted the old image class and re-generated a new one (above) based off the current model. I only did this because I did actually modify the Entity, adding the resource_updated_at attribute a while back. However, the result is still the same.  Hopefully you or someone can see something else.

Comment: Did you clean the project after changing the data model? Probably delete the old data store file from the app too.

Comment: Yup.. cleaned project tand always delete the app completely from the simulator when I change the model.

Comment: I also added my init method where the managedObjectStore and managedObjectContext are set up.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#configure-core-data-integration-with-the-object-manager. Particularly [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same error.  You need to use the managed version of RKObjectRequestOperation (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation).

Comment: This did it.. thank you so much! I was struggling with this for 2 days and finally just did a workaround so I could continue.. this made it correct.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with Core Data, you need to use a RKManagedObjectRequestOperation instead of RKObjectRequestOperation.